# What do curly braces in JavaScript mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found this in a jQuery file:

```
xxx.css({ 'float' : 'right' });
```

What do the curly braces do?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In your case it is an object passed to your css function.

```
myObj={} // a blank object
```

Here you can use this too

```
myObj={'float' : 'right'}
xxx.css(myObj);
```

Here is another example of object

```
var myObj={
    'varOne':'One',
    'methodOne':function(){ alert('methodOne has been called!')}        
}
myObj.methodOne();​ // It will alert 'methodOne has been called!'
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NyZDE/).

Comment: There is no good reason in creating a global variable for this purpose though.

Comment: Thanks and it was only for an example to make it clear to OP.

Comment: this is a question about _syntax_ and hence there absolutely exists brilliant reason in creating a variable for this purpose. In fact, perhaps the answer might want to include something along the lines of `myObj.varOne` takes the value of `'One'`

Answer (score 19):

The curly braces in the code you've shown define an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#using_object_initializers)

> #### Creating new objects You can create an object using an object initializer. Alternatively, you can first create a constructor
>
> function and then instantiate an object by invoking that function with
> the new operator.
>
> Using object initializers Object initializers are also called object
> literals. "Object initializer" is consistent with the terminology used
> by C++.
>
> The syntax for an object using an object initializer is:
>
> ```
> const obj = {
>   property1: value1, // property name may be an identifier
>   2: value2, // or a number
>   "property n": value3, // or a string
> };
> ```

Comment: But why does OP have 'float':'right' instead of float: 'right'? Like the link you asserted.

Comment: @KeKe both syntaxes are valid. The [language specification](https://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5) allows to define object property names using numeric literals, **string** literals (like in OP's example) and [identifier names](https://es5.github.io/#x7.6) (like in the Mozilla Developer Portal). The word `float` fulfills all syntax requirements of an identifier name, so quotes can be ommited.

Comment: @KeKe also please keep in mind, that `float` *was* a reserved word in ECMAScript 3. In the past (before ECMAScript 5 spec got released) [some browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Object/array_literal_extensions_Reserved_words_as_property_names) didn't allow reserved words as object property names without using quotes. Also some tools (e.g. [YUI Compressor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18533285/80720)) failed on such code.

Answer (score 13):

This is the top search engine result for "javascript braces". As such it's worth mentioning that braces in JavaScript can be used for:

- An [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) (as in the original question)
- A [code block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)
- [Object destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring)

Comment: But what is this, the inner one (In Quasar - Vuex documentation):   `const Store = createStore({
    modules: {
      showcase
    },
  })`

Comment: Object destructuring. `{showcase}` becomes `{"showcase":showcase}` to comply with the [Vuex API](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#modules). Proof: `{showcase}["showcase"] === showcase`

Comment: "code block" is important, and not mentioned in any other answer. Can you add links to all three ? Maybe [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [code block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) ?

Answer (score 9):

It's an object literal.

`var x = {'float': 'right'}` is the nicer/shorter form of `var x = new Object(); x.float = 'right';`

Answer (score 9):

In javascript curly braces are used for several purposes.

I your case these are used to create a key-value pair.

In others cases curly braces are used to combine a set of statements in a block.
And sometimes they are used to create objects
like var abc = { "a": 1, "b": 2 };

Answer (score 6):

Basically the curly braces {} are the another way for creating objects in javascript. This is equivalent to the "new Object()" syntax.

Answer (score 5):

That is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_literals)

> An object literal is a list of zero or more pairs of property names and associated values of an object

Answer (score 4):

curly braces identify an Object like so:

```
timObject = {
    property1 : "Hello",
    property2 : "MmmMMm",
    property3 : ["mmm", 2, 3, 6, "kkk"],
    method1 : function(){alert("Method had been called" + this.property1)}
};
```

in jQuery they are used to provide an Object with options for your method.
You could also write your code like so `xxx.css("width","10px").css("font-size","30px");` But passing it an Object makes it faster and more readable

```
xxx.css({"width":"10px","font-size":"20px"});
```

- http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Object

Answer (score 4):

Creates an object.

```
var myObject = {"element" : "value"};
alert(myObject.element); // Would alert: "value"
```

Answer (score -2):

They encapsualte the css attributes in this example.

Normally curly brackets represent a function or an encapsulated piece of code that needs to be executed as one.