# what do the {} mean for var ShopLogicOptions = {};

Tags: javascript, object

what do the `{}` mean for `var ShopLogicOptions = {};`

I have been searching on the net but that is a hard one to search for!

Is it declaring `ShopLogicOptions` as an object?

```
var ShopLogicOptions = {};
ShopLogicOptions.params = {orderId: '" + SS_JS_OrderNo + "', cartItems:[''], subTotal:'',
grandTotal:'', shippingTotal:'', discount:'', discountCode:'', productSku:'',
productName:'', productCategory:''};
```

Also, how do I properly insert my `SS_JS_OrderNo` javascript variable?

Comment: Try to ask just one question at a time.

Comment: I searched Google with *"JavaScript syntax"* and found an answer in the first result.

Comment: Please read about the JavaScript basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide. If you are new to a language, read its documentation first.

Comment: To be more concrete: [Values, variables, and literals (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2C_Variables%2C_and_Literals)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do curly braces in javascript mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699064/what-do-curly-braces-in-javascript-mean)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Derek has the correct answer. It's JSON (javascript object notation) you're right it's hard to google for. Check out this reference for more on JSON syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: The OP's question is about JavaScript, not JSON. Don't confuse these. JSON looks very similar to object literals, but they are two totally different things. The paragraph *JSON Uses JavaScript Syntax* in the w3school documentation is horrible wrong btw.

Answer (score 4):

`{}` means an empty `Object`. In the code, it means let `ShopLogicOptions` to be an object with nothing in it.