# What does this initialization do ? = {}

Tags: javascript

I've seen the folllowing:

```
var field = {};
field.tf = $("#textfield");
field.date = $("td#CurrentDate");
field.name = $("input#myname");
```

what does the initialization var field = {} do?
Is it creating a generic object (field) on which properties (field.tf) can be set on the fly?

Comment: 1) Object. 2) Yes.

Comment: *"Is it creating a generic object"* .... Answer: Yes, that's exactly what it's doing.

Comment: `{}` is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699064/what-do-curly-braces-in-javascript-mean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript has a number of different literal syntaxes beyond the standard `Number`, `String`, `Boolean` that are common to other languages:

```
foo = {};
```

is the same as:

```
foo = new Object();
```

While

```
foo = [];
```

is the same as:

```
foo = new Array();
```

and

```
foo = /foo/;
```

is the same as:

```
foo = new RegExp('foo');
```

These literal syntaxes have their own quirks and nuances. For objects, key-value pairs are comma separated with the keys and values separated by colon characters:

```
foo = {
    bar: 'baz',
    fizz: 'buzz'
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo = new Object();
foo.bar = 'baz';
foo.fizz = 'buzz';
```

For arrays, the array members are simply comma separated:

```
foo = ['bar', 'baz'];
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo = new Array();
foo.push('bar', 'baz');
```

<sub>Note that for arrays the constructor function has a flaw. `new Array(1, 2, 3)` is equivalent to `[1, 2, 3]`, but `new Array(3)` is not equivalent to `[3]`, it is instead equivalent to `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` (an array of size 3 with no members).</sub>

This convenient initialization structure, and the ability to nest objects and arrays within each other is what lead to the formalization of [the JSON data interchange format](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var field = {};
```

It represent an `object` datatype.

Comment: Not sure what `Kindly of saying that it is going to hold objects.` means, but everything is an object in JavaScript

Comment: @Chad yes right,  What I tried to convey is "A kind of predefined state" which is equivalent to `Object [] obj = new Object[];` in C#.  Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: saying `field={}` doesn't imply it will hold any data type, it only tells you that `field` is an instance of a plain object. It can hold anything: `field={ regx: /hey/, str: 'hey', obj: {}, fn: function() {} };`

Answer (score 2):

A generic object.

It is the same as:

```
var field = {
   tf: $("#textfield"),
   date: $("td#CurrentDate"),
   name: $("input#myname")
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it creating a generic object (field) on which properties (field.tf) can be set on the fly?*

Answer: Yes, that's exactly what it's doing.

For what it's worth, the code in the question could be simplified by defining all the properties in the initial declaration:

```
var field = {
    'tf'   : $("#textfield"),
    'date' : $("td#CurrentDate"),
    'name' : $("input#myname")
};
```

That does exactly the same as the original code, but a bit neater.

Answer (score 2):

var *something = {}* defines an object in JavaScript. So if you do not know what {} means, I assume that you don't have a full understanding of the 3 other lines of code as well. Let's give it a try:

So "field" is an object and you can give any structure to this object. It can have height, width, dimension and whatever you like. So, we defined our object like this:

```
var field = {};
```

Now, how do you add the properties to the object? In object oriented programming, we have the dot(.) notation. For example: person.name, requests the name of a person. According to your code:

```
field.tf = $("#textfield");
field.date = $("td#CurrentDate");
field.name = $("input#myname");
```

a) First you initialize the **tf of the field** to the value of your text box.
b) Secondly you initialize the **date of the field** to the value of your text box.

c) And finally you initialize the **name of the field** to the value of your text box.

You could also define your object as:

```
var field = {
'tf'   : $("#textfield"),
'date' : $("td#CurrentDate"),
'name' : $("input#myname")
};
```

I hope that helps! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That's just the standard notation for creating an empty JavaScript object. You'll see short-hand like this quite frequently:

```
var object = { };
var array = [ ];
```

Think of it as the minimalist version of a declaration:

```
var object = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}

var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as saying:

```
var field = new Object();
```

Another example is creating an array:
`var myArr = [ ]` vs `var myArr = new Array();`

Answer (score 1):

It is creating a javascript object by directly assigning object literal to it.

Object literals provide a very convenient notation for creating new object values. An object literal is a pair of
curly braces surrounding zero or more name/value pairs. An object literal can appear anywhere an expression
can appear:

```
var empty_object = {};
var stooge = {
   "first-name": "Jerome",
   "last-name": "Howard"
};
```