# What does this notation mean?

Tags: javascript

I found this code on a flex tutorial :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var params = {};
   params.quality = "high";
   params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
   ...
</script>
```

So what does the notation `var params = {};` mean ? What is created ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do curly braces in javascript mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699064/what-do-curly-braces-in-javascript-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a `literal object notation`. It basically does:

```
var params = new Object(); // same as var params = {};
```

When you use `{}` it creates an empty object. 
You could also add object properties directly; e.g.

```
var params = {
    quality: "high",
    allowscriptaccess: "sameDomain"
};
```

Here is an interresting [mozilla development link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals)

Answer (score 2):

> So what does the notation var params = {}; mean ? What is created ?

`{}` creates a new, empty object. This is called an "[object initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5)" (aka "object literal"). Then the object is assigned to the variable `params`, and the code follows on by adding a couple of properties to the object.

It could also have added the properties as part of the initialiser:

```
var params = {
    quality: "high",
    allowscriptaccess: "sameDomain"
};
```

You can also write `{}` as [`new Object()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.2.1) (provided the symbol `Object` hasn't been shadowed), but it's best practice to use `{}` (because `Object` can be shadowed).

MDN has a page on [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers). Oddly, that page primarily uses `new Object()` rather than `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var params = {};
```

This creates you an empty object.

With

```
params.quality = "high";
```

you are setting new parameters/fields of this object.

Answer (score 1):

`var params = {};` is an object.

The same as `var params = new Object();`

More information about objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1):

Its a way to create a javascript object, the code could also have been:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var params = {quality:"high", allowscriptaccess : "sameDomain"};
   ...
</script>
```