# How to push() things into an array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push an item into an array that in that have objects in them, like this:

```
var testarray = [
 {
  first: "See this?",
  second: "Oh my!"
 },
 {
  first: "Nice!",
  second: "Amazing!"
 }
]
```

You can see that I for this variable/array, I can't just use this `testarray.push("Wonderful!")`. Please show me how I can push things into these sort of arrays.

Comment: Instead of a String push an Object

Comment: why can't you use testarray.push("Wonderful!").?  that works just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do curly braces in JavaScript mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699064/what-do-curly-braces-in-javascript-mean)

Answer (score 2):

The "multiple things" are objects. Push another object in the same format.

```
testarray.push({first: "Wow!", second: "Wonderful!"});
```