# What does the "({})" do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

[image]

Just like the one displayed in the image. I am trying to know what does "({})" stand for and what's the specific meaning for it.

```
Page({     // Here

})
```

Looked for it up in search engines, no useful results showed up.

Comment: It calls a function named `Page` with an empty [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do curly braces in JavaScript mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699064/what-do-curly-braces-in-javascript-mean)

Answer (score 2):

`{}` in JavaScript is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```js
let obj = {
    // properties go here
    // can be empty
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`Page()` is a call of a function named `Page` with possible arguments between parenthesis.

`{}` is an empty object literal.

So the `Page({})` is a call with 1 argument being an empty object passed to a function being called.

But we have another context where we could encounter `({})`.

`{}` could be also a block of statements inside the parenthesis, for example `{ const test = true }`. A block his own scope where we can declare variables belonging to the block only. We use blocks as function bodies also. In an arrow function we have an interesting case:

`() => {}` - basically that's an arrow function with an empty block/body. But an arrow function could be bare (without a block) so in that case it returns the result of the expression after `=>`. Since `{}` is reserved for a function body, to return an object as an expression we should use:

`() => ({})`.

Another interesting case when should use `()` with `{}` to avoid `{}` being interpreted as a block is object assignment destructuring:

```
let prop1, prop2;
({prop1, prop2} = {prop1: 1, prop2:2});
```

And finally if you wan't to access a property in an object literal you should use `()` too:

```
({prop:1}).prop
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand what `({})` means, you need to understand what `{}` and `()` might mean.

`{}`:

- object literal: `{a: 1, b: 2}`, in which case an object is defined/created
- function block: `function() {}` or `() => {}` which specifies a function, but this is not your case, because this would have something else besides the `{}`
- etc. (code block, substring, like `"({})"`)

`()`:

- function parameter list, like `foo(param1, param2)`
- paranthesis operator, like `(a + b) * c`

Now, your example is clearly a function call and an object literal being passed to that function. Example:

```js
function foo(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}

foo({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
```

Here we can see that we have a function that takes a parameter and console-logs it out. We call this function, i.e., execute it and pass an object to it, so the object is logged to the console via the function.

Answer (score 0):

() has two meanings in Javascrip, one is function call, and the other is grouping. From this point of view, it should mean grouping, like this (1+2)x3.If it is a function, then the Function keyword needs to be used together.

{} can be represented as an object literal or a local scope. If it is a local scope, then some keywords need to be followed, such as for, function, etc. So this should be expressed as an object literal.

Combined, it should be a very high priority to create an anonymous object literal.