# Why doesn't calling a method directly from an object work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why does this work:

```
let user = { name: "John" };

user.name;   // John
```

but this doesn't:

```
{ name: "John" }.name or { name: "John" }['name']
```

What is the difference from the top block of code?

Comment: `({ name: "John" }).name`, otherwise it's a _block_ not an object. Note it would be easier to find the dupe if you included the way it specifically doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`{ name: "John" }` means a scope block with label `name` and a string literal `John` as an expression.

You should enclose it:

`({name : "John"}).name`

But if it's a part of an expression it would work fine:

`const name = {name: 'John'}.name;`

For other cases check [What does the "({})" do in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77851211/what-does-the-do-in-javascript/77851272#77851272)