# Using JSHint with Express.js / 'delete' (a reserved word)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jshint, gruntjs

I'm using Express.js ontop of Node.js to create RESTful API, and using grunt to watch my files and automatically lint my JavaScript.

Every time I use the delete function, it gets flagged by JSHint:

```
[L218:C9] Expected an identifier and instead saw 'delete' (a reserved word).
app.delete('/api/users/:userid', function deleteUser(req, res, next) {
```

I understand that 'delete' is a reserved word, but it's chosen by Express.js! Is there a better way to go about linting my Express.js app? Any way to turn off this check??

Comment: Doing a quick search I believe you can use `es5` option for that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Express.js, use `del` instead of `delete`.

```
app.del('/api/users/:userid', function deleteUser(req, res, next)
```

Comment: DO NOT USE del anymore!

express deprecated app.del: Use app.delete instead

Answer (score 7):

Another way to solve this would have been to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FMember_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FMember_Operators#Dot_notation).

```
app['delete']('/api/users/:userid', function deleteUser(req, res, next) {
  /* function body */
});
```

This sort of work around was necessary in the past when working with [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) which defines both `.delete` and `.continue` methods.

These days this sort of workaround should not be necessary. [Ever since ES5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17911822/778975) JavaScript has allowed property names to use reserved words. For a long time jsHint defaulted to assuming your code was ES3, but [starting with version 2.0.0](http://jshint.com/blog/2013-05-07/2-0-0/) it defaults to assuming it is ES5 and will not complain about reserved words being used as property names.

Answer (score 3):

In JSHint 1.1.x you can set the `es5` option for jshint, and it will allow you to use reserved words as properties per the ES5 specification.

As of JSHint 2.0 `es5` option is the default and you should be allowed to use reserved words as properties.

For more info you can head over to http://www.jshint.com/docs/#options

Comment: This has changed; [as of version 2.0.0](http://www.jshint.com/blog/2013-05-07/2-0-0/), JSHint got rid of the `es5` option and now assumes code is ES5 unless told otherwise via the new `es3` and `esnext` options.