# Is there a way to make 'constructor' a valid key in a JS object?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently making a chat AI that uses markov chains. One of the backend objects is an object that maps a string to any chain that it is a part of, such that:

```
var words = {}

words['test'] = [ ['this','is','a','test'], ['this','too','tests','things'] ]
```

Now, I have a problem. 'constructor' is a perfectly valid word, but it appears as though you can't map it as I have described above, as 'constructor' is a property of every object in JS (along with other things, of course). So to my question: is there a way to construct this map?

Comment: Can't you use a constructor function?

Comment: @elclanrs I think you missed the point of the question: I just wanted a map; no object functionality was needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`constructor` isn't a property of every object. Though by default every object created from literal syntax will have `constructor` in its prototype chain. This is because those objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, which does have that property.

One solution is to use objects that have no prototype chain.

```
var words = Object.create(null);

words['test'] = [ ['this','is','a','test'], ['this','too','tests','things'] ];
```

Now there will be no inherited properties to confuse things. This won't work in IE8 and lower though.

---

Another solution is to use `.hasOwnProperty()` to see if the `constructor` property is on the object itself or inherited. If inherited, then it's not the one you want.

```
if (words.hasOwnProperty("constructor"))
    console.log(words.constructor);
```

If the condition passes, then we know we're not using the inherited property, but rather the object's own property.

Comment: `.hasOwnProperty` will have issues if the key `hasOwnProperty` has been overwritten. The recommended solution for using an object as a hash map is to use a `has` function such as `function has(obj, key) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key) }`.

Comment: @zzzzBov:  If `hasOwnProperty` could be an own property on `words`, shadowing the prototyped one, then that would help. But if `.hasOwnProperty()` was actually *overwritten*, using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` won't really help. Maybe you were referring to the shadowing.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I never knew about `Object.create(null)`, and that did the trick.

Comment: @cookiemonster, i'm not sure I follow what you mean. `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` calls the function reference on `obj` without using the `hasOwnProperty` property on `obj`. That way it'll work for an example such as `obj = {hasOwnProperty: 'break everything'}`.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Right. You mentioned overwriting, which would imply that `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` itself had been altered. Your `obj = {hasOwnProperty: 'break everything'}` example isn't really overwriting it. It's just shadowing it. And in that case you're right. Getting `.hasOwnProperty` from the prototype would be the way to go.