# Create object with reserved words (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, object, private, public

How can I create an object like this in JS since public and private are reserved words

```
keyObject = {
    public : {
        iv: "123",
        key: "123"
    },   
    private : {
        key: "123"
   }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the keys in quotation marks. Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/17911822/1456234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the keys, like this:

```
var keyObject = {
    "public" : {
        iv: "123",
        key: "123"
    },
    "private" : {
        key: "123"
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5tUXy/

Answer (score 0):

you can define keys as strings

```
keyObject {
    'public': {
        iv: "123",
        key: "123"
    },
    'private': {
        key: "123"
    }
}
```