# IE8 error when using property name on an object

Tags: internet-explorer-8

var timer = {display:'x', at:'12/23/2016', in : 3000000};
var text = timer.display + " on " + timer.at + ".  Time Remaining : " + timer.in;

throws error in IE8 "Expected identifier, string or number"

var text = timer.display + " on " + timer.at + ".  Time Remaining : " + timer['in']; works!!!

This works fine in chrome, is .in a keyword and why only IE8 behaving weird?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `in` considered as a keyword? You could use:

```
var timer = {"display":"x", "at":"12/23/2016", "in" : "3000000"};
var text = timer.display + " on " + timer.at + ". Time Remaining : " + timer["in"];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Comment: in is keyboard but i was wandering its .in as obj.in, when used as keyword it is (var x in obj) not obj.in, and why it works fine in chrome, i was asking if "dot_in" is also considered keyword?

Comment: i think this might answer your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022397/using-reserved-words-as-property-names-revisited