# Set Default in JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Would this work say a new user registers for the site and I want the default role to be "user"?

I want that when a person signs up, the default role is set to "user", and be able to change it later to, let's say "admin".

```
  firstName: {
type: String,
required: true
},
lastName: {
type: String,
required: true
},
dob: {
type: Date,
required: true
},
email: {
type: String,
required: true
},
username: {
type: String,
required: true
},
password: {
type: String,
required: true
},
role: {
type: String,
default: 
}
});
```

Comment: no, it would not. you have to use a proxy to intercept missing property gets. alternaticely, you could use the default operator: `n={a:1,b:2}["c"] || 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this some kind of `Schema` (Mongoose) if yes then yes it will work.

Comment: Yes, it's a Mongoose schema.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer :) also please remember in future also mention which technology you are talking about you haven't mention mongoose anywhere which would deviate users from answering the right answers. Just remember.

Answer (score 0):

```
default
```

Is a keyword in JavaScript, so check out

[this stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7022397/3878933)

It basically says you're allowed to use keywords as object property names, since ES5.  Also, your property will remain unchanged until you change it somehow, so yes, it serves as a default value for that key.