# Workaround to allow reserved words to be used as property names on IE8?

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer-8, key, reserved-words

## Summary

I want to use `class` as a property name of an object, and access it using dot notation.

## Preamble

I already know that, according to [ECMA-262 5.1 Edition / June 2011](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (page number 19, page 31), `class` is a Future Reserved Word:

> **7.6.1.2 Future Reserved Words**
>
> (...)
>   **Syntax**
>
> ```
> FutureReservedWord :: one of
>     class    enum    extends    super
>     const    export  import
> ```

But, according to [ECMA-262 5.1 Edition / June 2011](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (page number 17, page 29), the restriction of not being a `ReservedWord` only affects `Identifier`, but not `IdentifierName`:

> **7.6 Identifier Names and Identifiers**
>
> (...) An Identifier is an IdentifierName that is not a ReservedWord
>   (see 7.6.1). (...)
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> Identifier ::
>     IdentifierName but not ReservedWord
> ```

And, according to [ECMA-262 5.1 Edition / June 2011](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (page number 67, page 79), an object property name is an `IdentifierName` instead of an `Identifier`:

> **11.2.1 Property Accessors**
>
> Properties are accessed by name, using either the dot notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression . IdentifierName
> CallExpression . IdentifierName
> ```
>
> or the bracket notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression [ Expression ] CallExpression [ Expression ]
> ```
>
> The dot notation is explained by the following syntactic conversion:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression . IdentifierName
> ```
>
> is identical in its behaviour to
>
> ```
> MemberExpression [ <identifier-name-string> ]
> ```

## Problem

The problem is that [some non-compliant browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5371101/1529630) throw an error when using reserved words as property names:

```
var obj = {class: foo};   // error
var obj = {'class': foo}; // ok
obj.class;                // error
obj['class'];             // ok
```

## What I want

Of course, I could use bracket notation instead of dot notation, but it becomes ugly with methods, because there are too many brackets:

```
o.if().class('foo').implements('bar').use().native().interface() // looks good
o['if']()['class']('foo')['implements']('bar')['use']()['native']()['interface']() //ugly
```

Then, I want a dirty hack (like HTC behaviours or things like that) that, when included using conditional comments, it makes dot notation work with reserved words, on IE8.

Comment: I can't imagine that any such thing is possible. The JScript runtime in IE8 is going to do what it's going to do.

Comment: @Pointy I'm also sceptical, but wanted to ask just in case