# How to not highlight object keys such as 'do'/'package' as keywords in Sublime?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, typescript, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 2/3 to code in Typescript and Javascript.

But when the key of an object is also a valid keyword name, it gets highlighted like a keyword even though it is only a key in that case.

Example:

```
var test = { do: 'hello world' };
```

Is there a way to *not* highlight this kind of key as a keyword would?

Comment: Quoting the key name woukd probably work (`'do': 'hello world'`), but really I would just try to avoid using keywords, even as keys.

Comment: Thanks for your help @IngoBürk. But why? It's supported by the language. How is that a problem if the editor recognises it fine and the language does too? I don't wee `do...while` used that much so for specific use cases, using `do` as a key can actually make things more readable. Also, this doesn't really solve the problem though. Just works around it.

Comment: Correct, it'd just be a workaround, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. And yes, it's perfectly legal to have such key names, it's just a personal opinion that I'd avoid them. It feels dirty to me. Not sure what your use-case for `do` is, but it is such a generic word that I would argue it's a good name. It's the "stuff" equivalent for verbs.

Comment: Actually, you might wanna take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298594/javascript-keywords-in-hash-keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax highlighting is controlled by the tmLanguage file.
In ST3 these are held in .cache files.

So follow these steps.

- Open `Tools -> Command Pallet` and Using Package Manager install [PackageResourceViewer](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer)
- In Command Pallet select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
- In the presented panel choose `JavaScript`
- In the presented panel choose `JavaScript.tmLanguage`

Now you have the language definition file displayed for you.

For your case do a search for `do` until you find it sitting in the list of keywords named `keyword.control.js`

```
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\b(break|case|catch|continue|default|do|else|finally|for|goto|if|import|package|return|switch|throw|try|while)\b</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>keyword.control.js</string>
    </dict>
```

Having tagged the string `do` as a JavaScript Control Keyword that instruction will be respected in the .tmTheme file you have chosen for your colour scheme.

If we use PackageResourceViewer in the same pattern as above to open the `Amy.tmTheme.cache` file and the search for `control` I find this instruction:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Control keyword</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>keyword.control</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#80A0FF</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

That says that if I chose to use the `Amy` theme then when a .tmLanguage file identifies a string as a `keyword.control` (a Control Keyword) the theme should apply the provided syntax highlighting.

So what does all that tell us?
If you want the string `do` to **not** *always* be treated as a Control Keyword you need to build a new set of regular expression (regex) tests than the ones currently in JavaScript.tmLanguage. If you can come up with a new regex that applies the rules you would like to have applied then you can add it to the .tmLanguage file and get the syntax highlighting you want.

I would **strongly** suggest that you start by saving the `JavaScript.tmLanguage` file into your `User` folder so you are working on a copy **and** your changes will not be discarded the next time ST3 upgrades.

Now work on editing the .tmLanguage file until you get the behaviour you want.
It seems to me your new regex should look for a trailing `:` immediately after the keyword and **not** tag such a string as `keyword.control.js`. Knock yourself out playing with the ideas. If you have saved a copy into your `User` folder and it all goes to custard the worst that can happen is you delete your .tmLanguage file and restart ST and you will revert to the default .tmLanguage file in the `Package` folder. The worst that can happen is you waste a couple of hours. But if you 'crack' the right regex pattern you have your own .tmLanguage file holding your preferred language definition that will be respected in every colour scheme and joy and happiness will abound in your world with an annoyance removed from your daily coding experience. Always a 'good thing (TM)'.

Hope this all makes sense. Yell out if it doesn't and I'll try and do better.