# How can I get SublimeText theme same as codepen.io

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, sublimetext

How can I get the text color theme of sublime text 3 to look like [codepen.io](http://codepen.io) twilight text color theme?

I literally just went through all themes in [colorsublime](http://colorsublime.com/) website, and didn't find anything close. They do have a [Twilight](http://colorsublime.com/theme/Twilight) theme, but it's completely different.

Here's an image of:

**codpen** with twilight theme:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to create your own syntax highlighting rules is one of the excellent features of SublimeText.

Have a look here at some other people wanting to build their own syntax highlighting rules:

[How to not highlight object keys such as 'do'/'package' as keywords in Sublime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172279/how-to-not-highlight-object-keys-such-as-do-package-as-keywords-in-sublime/23176904#23176904)

[Sublime Text - C++ Highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145265/sublime-text-c-highlight/23198103#23198103)

That explains the basic tools you need to use to do what you want to do.

Following the same ideas there you can build a syntax highlighting scheme for whatever set of preferences you have.

If you give that a try and have trouble with developing the relevant Regular Expression/s to do what you want to do then post what you have done and how it is not working the way you hoped and perhaps we can help you get to the end of the game.

Comment: Thanks! I asked a more specific question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874399/emulate-codepen-twilight-theme